# Is it dangerous for apache error_log to be writable?

Tags: apache, logging

I was reading an article about log files and referring to apache error log it mentioned that
the logfiles should not be writeable by other users.

How can this be dangerous? Is there a certain type of vulnerability that I should learn about ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Log files are often used to detect suspicious activities, like attacks.
But, if the log file can be modified by the attacker itself, (s)he can clean up the logs after the attack or plant false information which confuse the after-attack analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Servers need to save their activities and performance on specific files. `ErrorLog` is the file where Apache saves its errors defined by their name and location. So by understadning the role of this file you can guess that only the server itself must be allowed to write on this file otherwise miscreants will write anything else to mislead you to take actions that will help them to attack you later.

Answer (score 1):

Except for the log cleaning the other answers mentioned, there shouldn't be any danger from having a *writable* log file.

A *readable* log file on the other hand can lead to **log poisoning**, which can turn a local file inclusion into a code execution vulnerability.

The attack might look like this: An attacker visits `example.com/<?php // code you want to execute ?>` (or passes the php code via user agent or referer) - thus writing it into the log - and then visits `example.com/lfi_vuln.php?s=../../../error.log`. If the log file is readable, the code gets executed.